# I can't get the page's number from the url

Tags: php, get

I want to get the current page's number from the url:
localhost/MyWebsite/prdc?page=2

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
     $index = $_GET['page'];
     echo $index;
  }
```

And I get this error: Undefined index: page

And I don't find the id :
print_r($_GET);

> The output :
>
> Array ( [controller] => prdc [action] => [id] => )

Comment: config settings ?

Comment: If you are using any framework then go through their documentation to know how to pass Data in URL. Seems like you are searching for that ```page``` value at wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

By using getUriSegment() you can get a specific URI segment or return all segments available.

```
<?php

// if the url is http://www.timwickstrom.com/foo/bar/wow

echo getUriSegment(1); //returns foo
echo getUriSegment(2); //returns bar

print_r(getUriSegments()); //returns array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar', 2=>'wow')

?>
```

If you are using any framework like codeigniter then,

```
$segment= $this->uri->segment(2); //2 returns bar
```

Comment: Adding helper in controller as $this->load->helper('url');